# ¿Despúes de leer el archivo. json como puedo mostrar varios <li> que tienen una clase?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Tengo el siguiente archivo. json:

```
{
    "bc1" : "Intel® Core ™ i3 1115G4",
    "bc2" : "Intel® UHD Gráficos", 
    "bc3" : "8 GB DDR4 3200MHz SDRAM",
    "bc4" : "256 GB SSD M.2 PCIe®",
    "fichaTec" : ["<li class='subtituloCatFichaTec'>Sistema operativo</li>",
                      "<li class='detalleCatFichaTec'>Windows 10 Home</li>",
                      "<li class='espacioCatFichaTec'></li>",
                      "<li class='subtituloCatFichaTec'>Procesador</li>",
                      "<li class='detalleCatFichaTec'>Intel® Core ™ i3 1115G4</li>",
                      "<li class='detalleCatFichaTec'>2 núcleos / 4 hilos</li>",
                      "<li class='detalleCatFichaTec'>6M Cache, up to 4.10 GHz</li>",
                      "<li class='espacioCatFichaTec'></li>",
                      "<li class='subtituloCatFichaTec'>Gráficos</li>",
                      "<li class='detalleCatFichaTec'>Intel® UHD</li>",
                      "<li class='detalleCatFichaTec'>1.25 GHz</li>",
                      "<li class='espacioCatFichaTec'></li>"
                      ]
}
```

y en un .js tengo el siguiente código:

```
window.onload = cargar();

function cargar() {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET','URL del servidor',true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);            
            document.getElementById('b1').innerText = obj.bc1;
            document.getElementById('b2').innerText = obj.bc2;
            document.getElementById('b3').innerText = obj.bc3;
            document.getElementById('b4').innerText = obj.bc4;
            document.getElementById('b5').innerText = obj.bc5;
            for(var i = 0; i < obj.fichaTec.length; i++){
                //console.log(obj.fichaTec[i]);
                document.getElementById('brevesCaract') += obj.fichaTec[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lo que no tengo claro es de como recorrer el elemento arreglo "fichaTec" y de como obtener el valor para cada uno de sus elementos internos mediante el bucle for y poderlos imprimir/mostrar en una  que tiene de id="brevesCaract"; me podrían indicar sobre esta parte ya que lo anterior al bucle si me da resultado, gracias.

Comment: estas casi correcto. *brevesCaract* tiene que ser un `<ul>` y tienes que usar innerHTML para asignarlo con el operado `+=` por que si lo haces sólo con  `=` estas pisando el contenido en cada iteración del bucle y solo te va a aparecer el último elemento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas asignarlo como contenido HTML y no es necesario recorrer, puedes usar el método [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para unir todo en una cadena:

```
function cargar() {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET','URL del servidor',true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);            
            document.getElementById('b1').innerText = obj.bc1;
            document.getElementById('b2').innerText = obj.bc2;
            document.getElementById('b3').innerText = obj.bc3;
            document.getElementById('b4').innerText = obj.bc4;
            document.getElementById('b5').innerText = obj.bc5;
            // Agregar con innerHTML y .join()
            document.getElementById('brevesCaract').innerHTML + obj.fichaTec.join();
        }
    }
}
```